# Check the existence of variable in the global namespace without alternate name

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, namespaces, module-pattern

As a newbie in Design Patterns in Javascript, I came across the Module Pattern but I don't get something with namespace.

In [the namespacing part of Addy Osmani's online book about JS Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailnamespacing), Addy explains those 5 ways of checking for variable / namespace existence:

```
// This doesn't check for existence of "myApplication" in
// the global namespace. Bad practice as we can easily
// clobber an existing variable/namespace with the same name
var myApplication = {};

// The following options *do* check for variable/namespace existence. 
// If already defined, we use that instance, otherwise we assign a new 
// object literal to myApplication.
// 
// Option 1: var myApplication = myApplication || {};
// Option 2  if( !MyApplication ){ MyApplication = {} };
// Option 3: window.myApplication || ( window.myApplication = {} );
// Option 4: var myApplication = $.fn.myApplication = function() {};
// Option 5: var myApplication = myApplication === undefined ? {} : myApplication;
```

What I really don't get is how it solves the problem of naming.

Let's say myApplication is set up before my code tries to use myApplication. Using Option 1 for example (or actually all of the options), does not seem to change anything in case myApplication was already in use but only overwrite the previous values for myApplication:

```
// Higher in some script, where I don't know about it
var myApplication = 'whatever string or object used by the script';

// A bit of code later, where I come with my little Module Pattern
var myApplication = myApplication || {}; // Using Option 1

myApplication = (function($) {
   var myAppVariable = 'blabla';

   var myAppFunction = function() {
       // Doing a few things here
   };

   return myAppFunction;
}) (jQuery);

// Using the module
myApplication.myAppFunction();
```

To me it is very confusing because I don't see how it prevents me for also stepping on other's toes.

Comment: Ya that pattern won't preserve the original myApplication

Comment: But you're not following the pattern: you do a conditional assign, then immediately do an assign without checking. Assignment does precisely that; if you don't do anything to avoid stomping on your value, you don't do anything to avoid stomping on your value. What's the specific question?

Comment: @dave-newton I guess the specific question is how to avoid using myApplication if is already in used before (which I thought those Options were suppose to do)? Is there a short way to give an alternate name or something?

Comment: Those options *do* do that. Then you turn around and overwrite it by doing a direct assignment. I don't understand what the confusion is.

Comment: @dave-newton Ok, then I guess the confusion is about how "not turning around and overwritting it by doing a direct assignment", how to do the assignment properly.

Comment: @IamZesh ... Use one of the techniques you list.

Answer (score 0):

When you load a module in javascript, you're probably (depending on the code I guess) going to have to overwrite whatever variable is already in your modules namespace. A popular pattern for preserving whatever may have held your modules name before load is the `noConflict()` pattern. The idea behind this pattern is you hold the original value of your namespace in a variable and if `noConflict` is called, you replace your namespace with the original value and return your library. The pattern can be written more or less elegantly like this:

`myModule = "some stuff ya";`

```
(function(namespace, undefined) {
    var _module = "myModule";
    var __originalModule = namespace[_module];//holds the original value in case you wish to restore it

    /****** Code your module here following whichever module pattern you wish to follow ****/
    var module = {
        log: function() {
            if(console.log) {
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        }
    }
    /****** End of your module ****/

    //calling this method will remove your module from the namespace and replace it with whatever
    // originally held your module name.
    //This function returns your module
    module.noConflict = function() {
        namespace[_module] = __originalModule;
        return module;
    }

    namespace[_module] = module; //add your module to the namespace

})(window);

console.log(window.myModule); // => {log: function...}
var myMod = window.myModule.noConflict();
console.log(window.myModule); // => "some stuff ya"
```